# Как с помощью JQuery удалить теги блока, Не удаляя их содержимого?

Tags: html, jquery

Имеется конструкция типа:

```
<div class="tra-la-la"><a href="https://www.somewher.ru" class="bla-bla-bla"> ... много разного содержимого </a></div>.
```

Нужно убрать тег **a**, но т.к. содержимого в нём заключено много, unwrap вроде бы как не подходит.
Элементы каким-то загадочным образом (не наша админка) обернулись в такие ссылки, вот я их и разворачиваю.

Answer (score 0):

Для одного конкретного примера можно сделать нечто такое:

```
$('a').parent().html($('a').html())
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fbpg4so/2/)

---

Соответственно, можно "пробежаться" по всем ссылкам и выполнить такую операцию.

Но судя по описанию проблемы, уверен, что есть решение и получше. Рекомендую разобраться откуда взялись эти обертки.

Comment: Я так и начал сразу, но наш старший сотрудник просто полез решать проблему (недавно было подобное). Я сейчас поступаю так же, просто думал что сам быстро найду решение, но дело оказалось чуток сложней, чем я думал.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.tra-la-la').html($('.tra-la-la>a').html());
```

или

```
$('.tra-la-la').html($('.bla-bla-bla').html());
```